# Test Class for Controller Extension

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, apex

how do i write test class for controller extension. my code is below.

public AccountAndDetails (ApexPages.k controller) 
    {

```
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller extension is just another class. So you want to mimic calling the methods of that class within your test method:

```
@isTest
private class TestController {
    static testMethod void testOne() {
        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test account');
        insert acc;
        AccountAndDetails controller = new AccountAndDetails(new ApexPages.StandardController(acc));
        controller.methodOne();
        controlelr.methodTwo();
        // do some asserts
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Test Class with @isTest annotation. Then create some dummy data relevant to the object used in the controller class. Pass the dummy data to the methods defined in the extension class. Write some positive and negative test scenarios with proper assertions.